# In Git, what's the simplest way to get in the status "not currently on any branch"?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

In Git, what's the simplest way to get in the status "not currently on any branch"?

I am asking this because I rarely get in that status but with no clear awareness of the why.

I did a search for "not currently on any branch" in the book  [*Pro Git* by
Scott Chacon and Ben Straub](https://github.com/progit/progit2/releases/download/2.1.331/progit.pdf) but with no luck.

"The simplest" could be defined as with the minimum number of commands on the command line... but maybe then this question would be more suitable for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Checking out any commit (not a branch) will achieve this.

You can also just do

```
git checkout --detach
```

It will detach `HEAD` and point at the commit your current branch happens to point at.

---

*Differences between "not currently on any branch" and "HEAD detached at <hash>" messages are merely differences between git versions wording their output differently over time.*

Comment: Thank you but following your command I get from `git status`  the answer `HEAD detached at badf00d` and not "not currently on any branch".

Comment: "not currently on any branch" and "HEAD is detached" mean the same. I suspect version differences and output rewording.

Comment: There are indeed version differences. The detached at/from stuff is handled in modern Git by looking at the reflog for `HEAD`, so wiping out the reflog—which is in general a bad idea—will probably get you the less-useful message.

Comment: @torek I am not a connoisseur of the git source code, and maybe I am blatantly wrong, but it seems to me that "HEAD detached" and "Not currently on any branch" are both in the source code https://github.com/git/git/blob/8b7c11b8668b4e774f81a9f0b4c30144b818f1d1/wt-status.c#L1810

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson: the version differences are that the code for scanning the reflogs has gotten fancier over time. Go back to Git 1.7 and there's no code at all; go to 2.3, say, and it's much simpler and easier to get to the "Not currently on any branch" state.

Comment: @torek thank you, I slightly misunderstood Romain Valeri and your statement about git version differences.